# Create a progression tree in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

I am creating an app and I want to create a sort of leveling system like in the image below.
Once you complete level 1 you can proceed to level 2. Once you complete level 2 you can choose if you want to proceed to lever 3 or 4.

I want to be able to manualy create this sort of progression tree in flutter and change the color of the line between two levels once you procceed to the next level.

[image]

I tried to use packages like [game_levels_scrolling_map](https://pub.dev/packages/game_levels_scrolling_map) and [level_map](https://pub.dev/packages/level_map) but this isn't what im looking for because they lack the functionality to create subbranches in the progression tree.
Should I use flame to create this tree or is there another packlage/way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this package,

This might suit your needs.

```
https://pub.dev/packages/graphview
```

https://pub.dev/packages/graphview

Comment: This looks promissing, thank you I will check this out!